# Running Trac from USB stick (Windows)

Tags: usb-flash-drive, trac

I am looking for some way to run [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) on Windows from a USB stick (usb flash drive). User wants to carry a small USB drive, which will contain everything to be able to run Trac on his or some other Windows machine without any installation. Just connect USB, click and open web browser and use his Trac.

Generally it should be similar to Wiki on a Stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PortablePython and trac should be perfectly happy on a USB stick.  You could create an autorun to start tracd when you plug the USB drive in.

http://groups.google.com/group/trac-users/browse_thread/thread/fd7870b928650912/f5fa1e7d6c3563fa?lnk=gst&q=USB#f5fa1e7d6c3563fa

Comment: This looks promising, but the installation on USB stick is so slow that I am afraid it will finish tomorrow (maybe the antivirus is the real cause). This also rises the question of usability of such solution in terms of speed...

Comment: Trac on USB stick works fine, installation via ez_setup was flawless, speed is acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

[XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) can be used as portable LAMP stacks.

Comment: Thanks, this is not exactly what I needed, because Trac is using Python, but it pointed me in the right direction. Portable Python really exists - http://www.portablepython.com/